# how to show cos($kx$) is orthogonal to sin($kx$)?

Tags: fourier-series

In $\mathscr L_2$, it's easy to prove (cos$x$, sin$x$, cos$2x$, sin$2x$...cos$Nx$, sin$Nx$) is an orthogonal basis.

However, in $\mathscr L_2$, how to prove cos($kx$) is orthogonal to sin($kx$)? I am kind of lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general,
\begin{align*}
\sin \alpha \cos \beta = \frac{1}{2}[\sin(\alpha+\beta) + \sin(\alpha - \beta)]
\end{align*}
So,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(nx) \cos(mx) dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi[\sin(n+m)x + \sin(n-m)x]dx = 0
\end{align*}